# smallest pc case for mini-itx

Tags: pc, case

Have a mini ITX ASROCK motherboard at 6.7 inches square.  And existing tower is using a traditional ATX form factor power supply, 400 watt or thereabouts.

I want to transplant the motherboard to a new pc case.  I want to get the smallest case possible, in order to locate it on the desk with the monitor.

Space is limited, I can't place it under the monitor; the monitor cannot be raised up more than an inch.  But I can locate a new pc case if it's small enough behind the monitor.

Only have 2 ssd's to deal with, the 6.7" mini-itx mobo, and either existing ATX PSU but I am open to getting a new form factor PSU if needed to get the desired pc case.  There is no graphics card nor will there ever be a need for one.

It's an old person pc; solitaire is the only game, basic web & email access; should be zero heat generation.  Please recommend me a small pc case, or if there are any buzz words to use to properly search for one.

Comment: for anyone interested, I went with this off amazon for $85 with psu included; if i never comment back that means it worked out...  `IN WIN B1 Mini-ITX Tower Case - 200W 80 Plus Gold Power Supply Included - Tempered Glass Top Panel - 80mm Side Fan (IW-CS-B1BLK-PS200W)`

Comment: so in my comment directly above, that INWIN case came with a PSU included, and worked great.  I believe that is the smallest available, cannot see how it can happen any smaller unless they shrink the psu and do a motherboard smaller than 6" x 6".  It holds 2 regular size 2.5" SSD's.

Answer (score 0):

My ITX case knowledge is a bit outdated, but for the  smallest form factor ITX cases you will need an SFX power supply. The NZXT H1 was the smallest in 2020, and I think they have not gotten smaller yet. You will need to use water cooling for the cpu and an SFX power supply, but those are included with the case. If you need a dedecated GPU, you can do that with the PCIe riser.